# I cannot understand what the issue is with my code for an excercise

Tags: python, http, web-scraping

This code is from the famous Python for Everybody course on Coursera.

```
import socket
mysock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(("data.pr4e.org",80))


cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)


while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)  
    if len(data) < 1: 
        break
    print(data.decode(), end='')  # Decode the received bytes and print the data

mysock.close()
```

This works well and returns the content of the web address. But when I want to modify the code so that it asks for a web address and feeds the input to the program, it never stops running:

```
import socket
import re
mysock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

 try:
  webad=input("Enter your web address:")
  host_name=(re.findall("^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^\/\s]+)", webad))[0]
  mysock.connect((host_name,80))

except Exception as e:
  print(f"There is an error: {e}")

cmd_name=f"GET {webad}"+ " "+ r"HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
cmd = cmd_name.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)  
    if len(data) < 1: 
        break
    print(data.decode(), end='') 
mysock.close()
```

I don't really understand what the issue is. I tried checking the strings that get parsed, etc. They were all fine! Yet, the program goes on forever without doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Can you define "goes on forever" in more technical terms? Are you stuck in that `while` loop? If so, isn't it printing data?

Comment: PSA: If you're using `f` strings, which are very convenient, you don't need to do string concatenation as well.

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  For example, if the loop never stops, then that implies that `len(data) < 1` is never `True`.  Is that what your debugging is confirming?

Comment: What address did you enter?

Comment: Why do you use `re.findall()` if you're only interested in the first match? Use `re.search()`.

Comment: Making your code's indentation consistent will save you future pain. Right now you seem to use a mix of 1, 2, and 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is with the `cmd` that you're sending. if your print the original cmd it will look like this:

```
b'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'
```

while your modified code sends this `cmd`:

```
b'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\\r\\n\\r\\n'
```

This is happening because you're using `r"HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"` which is treating `\` of this part of the URL into a literal string, that's why your code is getting stuck on `data = mysock.recv(512)` line, it's not even completing one interaction of the while-loop. It's just waiting for the data to be received which it can't because the `url` you're connecting to is incorrect.

This is the normal behavior of the `socket` module, the socket is running in blocking mode (which is the default). You tell it to read, and it waits until new data arrives.If you don't want it to wait forever, you have to either:

- call `socket.settimeout()` with some seconds and then handle the timeout exception if it occurs during reading.
- use `select.select()` to detect when the socket has pending data to read before you then call socket.recv() to read I

Your corrected code should be like the following:

```
import socket
import re
mysock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    webad=input("Enter your web address:")
    # webad="http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt"
    host_name=(re.findall("^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^\/\s]+)", webad))[0]
    mysock.connect((host_name,80))

except Exception as e:
    print(f"There is an error: {e}")
    
cmd_name=f"GET {webad}"+ " "+ "HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
cmd = cmd_name.encode()

mysock.send(cmd)

# set a timeout so it stops after the defined time(seconds)
# if no data is received
mysock.settimeout(2)

try:
    while True:
        data = mysock.recv(512)
        if len(data) < 1: 
            break
        print(data.decode(), end='')
except socket.timeout:
    print("TimedOut! No response from server")
    print("check the url again")

mysock.close()
```

Output:

```
Enter your web address:http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 09 Jan 2024 22:30:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Sat, 13 May 2017 11:22:22 GMT
ETag: "a7-54f6609245537"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 167
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain

But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```